# Получить с клавиатуры трехзначное число и вывести сумму его цифр

Tags: javascript

// как решить задачу с помощью методов .reduce / или .map ?

```
 const a = +prompt('enter a positive tree-digit integer');
 if (a < 1000 && a > 100) {
  const b = String(a).split('');   // дальше этой строки не получается
  console.log(b)
} else(
  console.log('enter a three-digit positive number')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const a = 123;
const b = String(a).split('').map(i => Number(i)).reduce((r, i) => r + i);
console.log(a, b);
```

Comment: Благодарю. С ...reduce никак не разберусь.